# eclipselink cache

Tags: eclipselink

do i have to use elipselink as a persistence provider to make eclipselink cache working, please advise

Answer (score 2):

EclipseLink's cache is built in for use with EclipseLink JPA or native ORM. It is not designed for use outside of this context.

Doug